# Is there a non ugly way to create a slideToggle effect without jquery?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to make a slide out menu, which I've got working.   Here's what I have:

```
    var navHeight = 0;
    function slideToggle() {
        var animSpeed = 5;
        var navList = document.getElementById("mainNav").getElementsByTagName('ul');                
        if(getComputedStyle(navList[0], null).display == "none") {  
            var time = setInterval(function() {
            navList[0].style.display = "block";
            if(navHeight < 116) {
                navHeight += animSpeed;
                navList[0].style.height = navHeight + 'px'; 
            }
            else {
                navList[0].style.height = "auto";
                clearInterval(time);
            }
        }, 5);
        }
        else {
            var time = setInterval(function() {
                if(navHeight > 0) {
                    navHeight -= animSpeed;
                    navList[0].style.height = navHeight + 'px'; 
                }
                else {
                    navList[0].style.display = "none";
                    clearInterval(time);
                }
            }, 1);
        }   
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rzjaz5k5/

Like I said, it works pretty much as expected.  I, however, would like to do something like this and actually have it work:

```
<script>
    var animSpeed = 5;
    function slideToggle() {
        var navList = document.getElementById("mainNav").getElementsByTagName('ul');                
        if(getComputedStyle(navList[0], null).display == "none") {  
            var time = setInterval(slideDown(time, navList), 5);
        }
        else {
            var time = setInterval(slideUp(time, navList), 1);
        }   
    }
    function slideDown(time, navList) {
        if(getComputedStyle(navList[0], null).height < 116) {
            navList.style.height += animSpeed + "px"; 
//obviously this^ isn't actually going to work because style.height isn't actually a number so I'm going to have to use an intermediate variable but this is the ultimate goal. I actually have to do this:
             x += animSpeed;  //This x has to be a global variable with the current height of my list.
             navList.style.height = x + "px"

        }
        else {
            x = 0;
            clearInterval(time);
        }
</script>
```

I can actually get this to work except for being able to exit out of the interval once it's started.  I'm sure I can fix this by just forgetting about the setInterval() function and just doing all the timing myself(if javascript actually has a decent function to get time) but I want to know if there's any way to make this work the way it is first.

Comment: Your post is rife with insults towards the people from whom you're asking help. Even your username implies disdain for web development. I think you'll have better luck getting help if you reword your question (and name) more politely. See: [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Even if I am misreading it, your post contains a lot of "fluff" that should be removed. See: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

Comment: Whatever your feelings towards standard bodies, you can still keep it professional and courteous. I've removed the banter and innate language, so people can focus on your question and not your views.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thank you.  I'm actually quite enjoying web development and making fun and interesting things happen on something that was designed to display static documents, despite all the hackiness.  It's very fun.

Comment: The web—the world—changes. Perhaps it was once designed "to display static documents"—it no longer is. I wouldn't describe the system as "hacky." In fact, I think one of the greatest (and most fun) parts of web development is getting all the little pieces to seamlessly fit together. Of course, you can get this satisfaction from designing any program; web development just seems to be a little better at providing it (imho).

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Tricks has a collection of tricks involving the checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/), this uses a simple checkbox to maintain state and use css styling and animations on adjacent elements, it includes a slider in pure html/css

simple slide toggle demo:

**css**

```
/* Checkbox Hack */

input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
label { 
  -webkit-appearance: push-button;
  -moz-appearance: button; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 60px 0 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Default State */
.toggled {
   background: green;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   max-height: 0;
   transition: max-height 0.1s ease
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .toggled {
   max-height: 100px;
   transition: max-height 0.1s ease
}
```

**html**

```
<label for="toggle-1">I'm a toggle</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div class="toggled">I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, added simple css-only demo